# Elastic seach group by and get first record

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by, elasticsearch-5

I am new to Elastic Search, 
I want to create a query in the elastic search which works like a group by SQL.
Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT top 100  *
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
OVER(PARTITION BY columnA
ORDER BY columnB) AS StRank, *
FROM table where columnA in ('a','b','c') ) n
WHERE StRank IN (1) 
GO
```

I want a single row group by columnA and Order by  columnB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html).

> Allows to collapse search results based on field values. The
>   collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per
>   collapse key

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {- -> filter doesn't calculate score(if score needed use must)
        "terms": {
          "columnA": ["a","b","c"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse": {      --> top 1 Group by column A
    "field": "columnA"
  },
  "sort": [          --> sort 
    {
      "columnB": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "collapse" only works with keywords and numbers, but mine columnA is a string. How will I handle that? @jaspreet-chahal

Comment: In your index mapping you can create a sub field of type keyword. If mapping is not explicitly created then field will already be existing ex "columA":{ "type" : "text" ,fields:{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}. Try using "columnA.keyword " if it does't exist then create one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: field with type text are stored as tokens . ex ColumnA: "A B". is stored as two seperate token A and B . It is suitable for match etc but queries which need entire text can't work on these ex. term, collapse etc. Type keyword will store text as ''A B". Using subfields allows to store same fields in different ways

Comment: Is there a way to get total number of collapsed docs "per bucket" with the collapse clause?

Comment: @SamChats You need to use terms aggregation for that. Query section will not give you analytics info. Collapse is  usually preferred for search use cases that don't require analytics on the collapsed results.